# Extracting characters from a string using a list of indexes

Tags: python

I have a string and list of indexes. I would like to extract characters from string at the positions indicated in the list to make a substring.

For example:

```
str = "Hello Stack Overflow"
lOfIndexes = [1,3,6]
```

I would like to get `elS`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no builtin function to do this, but it's simple enough with list comprehension.

```
>>> ''.join(str[i] for i in lOfIndexes)
>>> 'elS'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect use for [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

s = 'Hello Stack Overflow'
print ''.join(itemgetter(1, 3, 6)(s))
# OUT: 'elS'
```

Comment: This is really good. But you should edit your answer so it works for dynamic lists of indexes. Specifically, you should construct the itemgetter object as `itemgetter(*lOfIndexes)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
some_string = "hello world"
indicies = [1,3,2]
output = []
for i in indicies:
    output.append(some_string[i])

print ''.join(output)
```

Comment: You can avoid constructing the entire list by using a generator object.